# Different width of column in tables

Tags: html, css

I am having some trouble when creating an `HTML` table.

I would like to make the width in the odd column as 10%, 70% and 30% form left to right(red). Width in even column is 50% and 50% from left to right(blue).

By the way, can I set the width in `CSS`?

### HTML:

```
<table id="report" class="display" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Gorup #</th>
            <th>Match Key</th>
            <th>Mail Type</th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="top">
            <th>0</th>
            <th>Match Key</th>
            <th>Marketing</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="top">
            <th>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <th>sample_path_01</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>sample_path_02</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>sample_path_03</th>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </th>
            <th>
                <li>Screenshot</li>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="top">
            <th>1</th>
            <th>Match Key</th>
            <th>Marketing</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="top">
            <th>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <th>sample_path_01</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>sample_path_02</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>sample_path_03</th>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </th>
            <th>
                <li>Screenshot</li>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xQ7Pv/11/)

Comment: Don't pretend your JS Fiddle link is code (it isn't); add your code to your question (as the dialogue should have told you to do when you wrote your question). You've asked 32 questions, and have sufficient reputation, now, to have understood the community's expectations at this point.

Comment: I've included the link for you, actually you need to put the code inside your question, not just the link itself

Comment: I've close voted your question as it lacks information for the issue you are facing. Please share the relevant code here

Comment: @DavidThomas Really? Use your brain. [His Code](http://jsfiddle.net/xQ7Pv/11/). Maybe they are not to good with JS Fiddle and deleted it by accident. Changing the last number on the URL will show the update before.

Comment: @Ruddy: yes, really. He should certainly, by now, have known to include code in the question. The error message that pops up while *writing the question* would have said as much.

Comment: @Jimmy You may want to fix your question a little bit as it doesn't make to much sense. Also yes you can set width in `CSS` by using `width: 50%;` or whatever value you want.

Comment: Setting `width: 50%` in `CSS` would apply to all `th`, but I'd like to set different width in different `th`.

Comment: @Jimmy There are all kinds of selectors. You could use `CSS3` if you wanted. Using `th:nth-child(1)`, this would select the first one. Or you could give them class's etc. Many ways you could do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just check the table and find that its not in correct format.

`<th>` is missing in the table.

the table structure should be like this.

```
<table id="report" class="display" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Gorup #</th>
                    <th>Match Key</th>
                    <th>Mail Type</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>0</th>
                    <th>Match Key</th>
                    <th>Marketing</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <table border="1" colspan="2">
                          <tr><th>sample_path_01</th></tr>
                          <tr><th>sample_path_02</th></tr>
                          <tr><th>sample_path_03</th></tr>
                        </table>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <li>Screenshot</li>
                    </th>
                     <th>&nbsp;</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>1</th>
                    <th>Match Key</th>
                    <th>Marketing</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <table border="1">
                          <tr><th>sample_path_01</th></tr>
                          <tr><th>sample_path_02</th></tr>
                          <tr><th>sample_path_03</th></tr>
                        </table>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <li>Screenshot</li>
                    </th>
                    <th>&nbsp;</th>
                </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

this is really impossible for 1st row column in different width and for another row column have different width.

anyway you can give the width a differnt width in columns

here is the little modified CSS code.

```
#report > tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > th{
        background-color: #f00;
}

#report > tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > th:nth-child(1){width:10%; color:#fff;}
#report > tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > th:nth-child(2){width:70%; color:#00CC33;}
#report > tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > th:nth-child(3){width:30%; color:#CC9900;}
#report > tbody > tr:nth-child(even) > th{
        background-color: #00f;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I use `colspan="2"` in `th`.

Comment: did you achieve the results or you are still loooking for an answer? or if you like my answer please vote.

Answer (score 0):

CSS

```
#report > tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > th:first-child{
    width:10%;
    background-color: #f00;
}
#report > tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > th:last-child{
    background-color: #f00;
    width:20%;
}
#report > tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > th:nth-child(2){
    background-color: #f00;
    width:70%;
}
#report > tbody > tr:nth-child(even) > th{
    background-color: #00f;
     width=50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write like this:

table tr th:first-child{ width: 10%}

table tr th:nth-child(3){ width: 70%}

table tr th:nth-child(5){ width: 30%}

table tr th:nth-child(even){ width: 50%}